# How to create a new anchor tag around an existing element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<span class="classname">
<img src="" width="70" height="70">
</span>
```

I'm trying to add an anchor tag with a URL around the  tags. I'm not sure how to do it and I've been stumped for hours..

Comment: around `span` or `img`?

Comment: can't you add it in the markup directly? what problem are you facing? what should be the expected behavior?

Comment: you have to explain in details. What exactly you want to see in output

Comment: Around the span tag. I need to do it in javascript.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is just [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the jQuery [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method,

```
$("span.avatar").wrap("<a></a>");
```

Pure JS:

```
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("avatar")[0];
var wrap = document.createElement("a");

target.parentNode.replaceChild(wrap, target); 
wrap.appendChild(target);
```

Comment: How would you do it without jquery?

Comment: Adding an answer give me sometime

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(wrap);` will append the element to the end of the body, not necessarily where the element was originally.

Comment: @FelixKling Correct, but, since I don't have the rest of the markup, I don't really have a choice.

Comment: You could use [`.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild) or `.insertBefore`, like Arun in his answer.

Comment: @FelixKling with `.replaceChild()` I'd need to create a clone and then do it, which seems unnecessary. `.insertBefore()` seems ideal, but again, I'd need some more markup for it.

Comment: No, you don't need a clone. `target.parentNode.replaceChild(wrap, target); wrap.appendChild(target);`. And no, you don't need markup for any of these methods. Why do you think you do? You already have all required values to pass to those methods.

Comment: @FelixKling `target.parent` will return `undefined`, although `document.body.replaceChild(wrap, target)` works fine

Comment: That's why I already fixed the code long time ago ;) (`parent -> parentNode`). `document.body.replaceChild` only works if `target` is a child of the body.

Comment: No, and I still don't understand why. `target.parentNode` returns a reference to the element's parent which is all you need. You don't have to know what element it is. The only bit that depends on the markup is selecting the target element at the beginning.

Comment: what if there's no parent element?

Comment: Then you cannot select the element to begin with since it is not part of the document. Every node in the document has a parent.

Comment: what if it's a direct child of the `body`? in that case, `target.parent` returns `undefined`

Comment: I told you `parent` was a *mistake*. I immediately correct the code to use `parentNode` instead. If the parent is the body then `parentNode` will return a reference to `document.body`. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode.

Comment: Phew! perfect. Will update my answer. cheers, learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('avatar')[0];
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
el.parentNode.insertBefore(anchor, el);
anchor.appendChild(el)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xDyz2/)

Comment: You're assuming there's a `<div>` wrap, which may not be the case