# Inject anchor tag around existing text with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML on a page that reads as follows:

```
<h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_History"></a>History</h3>
```

I am running some javascript in the page READY where I am creating a dynamic hyperlink and I would like that to be inserted so that when the page renders the final result is:

```
    <h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_History"></a><a href="https://thissite.com/newurl" target="_blank"> History</a></h3>
```

The class name of the H3 exists on multiple page elements. The Name of the anchor tag, SPBookmark_History, is unique.

How can I accomplish this using JQuery or straight javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new anchor tag around an existing element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161631/how-to-create-a-new-anchor-tag-around-an-existing-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): in order to select the element because SPBookmark_History is unique
- [.closest( selector )](https://api.jquery.com/closest/): to get the parent h3 element.
- [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/): Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.
- [filter-function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function): in order to get only the text after the link
- [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/): Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

The code:

```js
$('a[name="SPBookmark_History"]').closest('h3.ms-standardheader')
.contents().
filter(function (idx, ele) {
  return ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
})
.wrap($('<a/>', {href: "https://thissite.com/newurl", target: "_blank"}));

console.log('Result is: ' + document.getElementsByClassName('ms-standardheader')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_History"></a>History</h3>
```

Comment: but the name of the anchor is unique so it works only for this one not for all, isnt better use $('.ms-standardheader a')? or am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var link = $('a[name=SPBookmark_History]');
  link.attr('href','https://thissite.com/newurl');
  link.attr('target','_blank');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2wpngm78/)

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Fahid.  That adds an href to the SPBookmark_History anchor but that is not what is requested. I want to add a new anchor tag around the text portion of the H3 that follows that anchor.