# How to add an url to image by css?

Tags: html, css

I have following css and html:

CSS:

```
<style>
#sprite {
    height:30px;
    width: 40px;
    background: url(/images/forCSS/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -465px; /*152 i unit*/
    border:1px solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sprite">
</div>
```

In this div display an image.

How to add an url to this image?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? You're already using a background image

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Like this? [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2WN73/) Or like this? [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2WN73/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<a href="url">
   <div id="sprite"></div>
</a>

#sprite {
    height:30px;
    width: 40px;
    background: url(/images/forCSS/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -465px; 
    border:1px solid;
    float:right; /* add this */
}
```

or you can do this:

```
$('#sprite').click(function(){
  window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can just use normal HTML for it, I see no reason to do it this way. OP and @sapphireNK explain to me the need to use jQuery for the link? I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: there are 2 kinds of solutions, probably he can't change html by any reasons.

Comment: You know wrapping a `<a>` round a `div` is not valid HTML as the syntax is incorrect right? Hence the second part of my answer. Also for your option he has to change the HTML to add the `<a>`.

Comment: my post edited by theme author http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21181214/revisions, my code was:
`<a href="url">
   <span id="sprite"></span>
</a>
#sprite {
display:block; ......`

Answer (score 1):

If your asking to put a link via `CSS` on that `div`, to my knowledge this is not possible. You options are the following:

### HTML:

Wrap the `div` in `<a>`

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"><div></div></a>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat;
    width: 570px;
    height:150px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2WN73/)

---

Or we can put the `<a>` inside the `div` and set its `height` and `width` + the `display: block;`. This is a better option and has valid syntax. The one above works but is more or a hack` then anything.

### HTML:

```
<div><a href="https://www.google.com/"></a></div>
```

### CSS:

```
div {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat;
    width: 570px;
    height:150px;
}
a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/2WN73/1/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#sprite {
 height:30px;
 width: 40px;
 background: url(http://omegazelda.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/orace-and-minish-sprite.png) no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px -465px; /*152 i unit*/
 border:1px solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="sprite"></div></a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucUhUhU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't add a URL via css. It is possible using JavaScript though, see [How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Code-

```
<div id="sprite">
   <a href="#" class="invisibleLink"></a>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
#sprite {
height:30px;
width: 40px;
background: url(/images/forCSS/sprites.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0px -465px; /*152 i unit*/
border:1px solid;
}
.invisibleLink{
display:block;
height: 30px;
width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Check now. I add corresponding CSS.