# Why is .innerText not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Here is my code 
It's working perfect in all browsers **but not in Firefox.**

I tried many thing but didn't work at all.
Please can some one help me on this issue.
Am I doing something wrong.?

Is there any other way.?

I'M USING .innerText because values are coming from

```
<span class="jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0">
 4.5
</span>
```

There is no error on console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery('#submitButton').click(function(){
   var PostStartone = document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').innerText;
   var PostStarSec = document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-1').innerText;
   var PostStarThird = document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-2').innerText;
   var PostCapVal = document.getElementById('code').value;
   var PostRBVal = "";
   var selected = jQuery("div.jr_fieldDiv input[type='radio']:checked");
   PostRBVal = selected.val();
   jQuery.post("http://xyz/x/Update.php", { 
      GetStarOneValue : PostStartone ,
      GetStarSecValue : PostStarSec ,
      GetStarThirdValue : PostStarThird ,
      GetCaptchValue : PostCapVal,
      GetRadioBTNValue : PostRBVal});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, which bit of that code isn't working. Have you put breakpoints in it to see the point it gets to before breaking?

Comment: What is `getParameterByName`?

Comment: Please mention error, and where it is coming...how do u ensure it is not working...

Comment: The problem is that you loaded the page and, when you didn't see the expected functionality, you simply stared at the screen. Come on, do some active debugging. The JavaScript console exists since the 1990s and nowadays we have lots of awesome developer tools.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario As far as I can tell, this is a silent error where values are mysteriously blank ;)

Comment: use $("#id").text() instead writing in old way as document.getElementById('id').innerText

Comment: hey come on...the total code in click event function...and you are saying that click event is not working......

Comment: Can you show the order in which you are structuring your document (where you include jQuery). etc. If it is failing silently, the events probably aren't being attached.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`innerText` is the "old Internet Explorer" way of doing it.

Try `textContent` instead. Ideally you should use `elem.textContent || elem.innerText`, but if you're using jQuery you can just do `jQuery("#the_id_here").text()`.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: @user3474130 Please provide feedback that helps us solve your problem. To be clear, do you mean that `var PostStartone = document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').innerText || document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').textContent;` is not working, or that `$('#jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').text()` is not working? This answer supplies two suggestions; it would be helpful if you could explain exactly *how* each solution is failing,

Comment: @user3474130 Have you tried `var PostStartone = document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').innerText || document.getElementById('jr-rating-wrapper-jr_stars-new-0').textContent` as suggested in this answer? Did it not work?

Comment: There is problem with those 3 variable any thing else is working good if define variable manually.

Comment: It's like talking to a brick wall... ***TRY `textContent`!***

Comment: -1, sorry, but nope. `innerText` is more [profoundly different](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) from `textContent`, and actually is tremendously more useful. `innerText` gives an "approximation" of how the text is _actually presented_ in the browser, as opposed to `textContent`, which returns just about the _tag-stripped markup source_, adding very little value, or even extra problems (like the loss of word boundaries).

Comment: @Sz. Interesting link, however I personally stand by `textContent` as the "more correct" option here, specifically because it preserves the source. That being said I've only ever really used these on tiny things like `<span id="output">--</span>` or the like so y'know my opinion may not count for much XD

Comment: Niet, another interesting fact I learned since then: now Firefox has finally joined the others, and also implemented `innerText` as well (in 45+). (It's actually not a matter of correctness, they are different features. Sometimes you may need the source, as you noted, and there are cases where you'd need the ("rendered") text roughly as the user can actually see it. And it's a nice, fat can of worms either way. :) )