# Cross browser issue with inner text

Tags: jquery, innertext

I have this below code

```
var tempqStr = $("#Qpanel" + item.data("question-id") + " > .questions")[0].innerText
```

This works fine in **Chrome** but in **Firefox and IE** I get an error inner text is undefined.Any suggestions on how to make that code work in all the browsers?

Comment: Check [`Niet the Dark Absol answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22990890/769678) for this question [Why Is Inner Text Not Working In Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990812/why-is-innertext-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#Qpanel" + item.data("question-id") + " > .questions")[0].text();
```