# Getting the text of a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the text of all hyperlinks in my web page and check whether the text is "selected". If it is "selected", an alert showing the  id will be prompted.

However, when I tried to use inputs[i].value to get the text of the , the result I gets was "undefined".

How can I go about doing it?

The following codes are for my hyperlinks:

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="1">selected</a>
<a href="www.facebook.com" id="2">select</a>
<a href="www.gmail.com" id="3">selected</a>
<button onclick="check()">Check!</button>
```

The following codes are for my javascript:

```
function check() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].value == "selected")
        {
            alert(inputs[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @alcoholisevil It's `textContent` or just `text`, not `textValue`

Comment: you could use .innerText or .innerHTML as the anchor element does not contain any value property.

check my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6Lambn3/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `textContext` instead.

```
if (inputs[i].textContent == "selected")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6cpvt5e/2/

Comment: [HTMLAnchorElement.text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement). Depending on its existance seems like a terribad idea though; especially as it’s not there on all elements. Better use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) directly.

Comment: I would add a trim() to compare. Since the value could also be 'selected '.

Comment: @JavaScript Not the OP's request. They might not want to capture white space.

Comment: It never hurts to hint it out tho.

Comment: @JavaScript It's a fair point but I would rather capture the white-space before it's rendered to the client than hack a fix in a lookup.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there any reason to not use the faster === in this case?

Comment: @Javascript I don't think this will be any faster in this instance as the types are the same. Furthermore this isn't a full code review, I'm just answering the OP's question.

Comment: “Faster”? It’s not about speed, it’s about teaching proper ways to solve problems, not setting bad examples that solve *this problem* but will cause new problems later.

Comment: @poke I agree, but as I stated this isn't a code review. If it was I would pay more attention to `onclick` attribute over an event listener, than the conditional operator.

Comment: It's content, not context.

Comment: @alcoholisevil Cheers, was correct in jsfiddle, but typo on SO

Answer (score 2):

Use `innerText`. It's not a value on the `<a>` but actually a text node inside it.

`if (inputs[i].innerText === "selected")`

Edit: Use `innerHtml` instead ;)

Comment: `.innerText` won't work in FireFox. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22990890/4338417](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22990890/4338417)

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla thanks didn't know it was an IE thing - just seemed handy as an easy way of handling `<em>selected</em>` for example

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the text of `<a>` tag is `.innerHTML` **NOT** `.value`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/g6dhp19n/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
function check() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    if (inputs[i].innerHTML == "selected") {
      alert(inputs[i].id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="1">selected</a>

<a href="www.facebook.com" id="2">select</a>

<a href="www.gmail.com" id="3">selected</a>

<button onclick="check()">Check!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

HTML

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="1">selected</a>
<a href="www.facebook.com" id="2">select</a>
<a href="www.gmail.com" id="3">selected</a>
<button onclick="check()">Check!</button>
```

Javascript

```
function check() {
                var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (inputs[i].innerHTML == "selected")
                    {
                        alert(inputs[i].id);
                    }
                }
            }
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf1qvk3d/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerText` as.

```
if (inputs[i].innerText == "selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerText` instead of `.value`

```
if (inputs[i].innerText == "selected")
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if(this.text() == 'selected')
        alert($(this).attr(' id'));
}
```