# How to get the text of <a> tag with MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, onclick

I followed some StackOverflow questions like this one [Getting the text of a <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453225/getting-the-text-of-a-a-tag) but I still can't get my text.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
var ul = document.getElementById('listExisting');
var li = document.createElement("li");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "#");
a.setAttribute("class", "oneExistingFile");       a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("example"+i))
li.appendChild(a);
ul.appendChild(li);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.oneExistingFile').click(function() {
    console.log(this.textContent)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="listExisting">
</ul>
```

Here it works but in my code I have `undefined` despite it's really the same structure [image]

What am I doing wrong ?

My listener is like this with Meteor:

```
  'click .oneExistingFile': function(event, template){
    console.log(this.textContent);
  }
```

Comment: `this.textContent` seems to get the text just fine.

Comment: @JJJ it looks like not here

Comment: Well we can't really tell why it wouldn't work in your code. You'll have to come up with a demo that replicates the problem.

Comment: @JJJ I can't really provide more, I added my MeteorJS method

Comment: why this is tagged as meteor?

Comment: @iiro because I use MeteorJS and as the listener (last block of code)  is a Meteor template event

Comment: Note that Meteor's click listener is not the same as jQuery's click listener. In Meteor, `this` doesn't point to the element.

Comment: @JJJ thank you really much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
'click .oneExistingFile': function(event, template){
    console.log(event.target.text);
  }
```

Comment: It would work too :) thank you !