# Create anchor tag inside of Javascript write statement

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates text using write statements. How could I rewrite the following so the word "here" is an clickable anchor tag?

href = www.example.com target =_blank id = link

```
.write("website:Click here to visit our website.",800)
```

Comment: JavaScript Front-end or node.js?

Comment: javascript front end

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"www.example.com");
aTag.setAttribute('target',"_blank");
aTag.setAttribute('id',"link");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

**UPDATE:** Using `Write()`

```
document.write("website:Click <a href='http://www.google.com' 
               target='_blank' id='link'> here</a>to visit our website.");
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that does not show me how to add it to the write statement.

Comment: when I tried your update I get "here" and everything to the right as a link that when it is clicked does nothing.

Comment: The fiddle works, but does not work in my script.  All of this becomes a link "here to visit our website"

Comment: @Kurt Marshman: The anchor tag is not closed. now i check the updated result.

Comment: I seen you had not closed it, but I did. Still does not work.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari and all of them are doing the same.

Comment: @Kurt Marshman: Check the Console tab in Developer Tools(RightClick -> InspectElement -> Console) in Chrome browser, whether any error is showing.

Comment: No errors... looked at that now and before I submitted the question. Just seems like the anchor tag is not getting closed.

Comment: I found other js was creating the issue so I am off to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var mydiv =document.getElementById("myDiv");
mydiv.innerHTML = "click <a href='yourLinkAction'>here<\a> to go to website";
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `.write()` method is used for directly writing on your `HTML`. So you can't change it later after you've already written. Try the following way,

```
function WriteNow(){
    document.write("website:Click <a href='http://www.google.com/' target =_blank id ='link'>here</a> to visit our website.",800);
}
WriteNow();
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/447brajk/)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I get "here" and everything to the right as a link that when it is clicked does nothing

Comment: @Ashod Shanto I found other js was creating the issue so I am off to figure that out.