# Creating an href on Returned JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json

I have some basic JSON data returned from an ajax request which populates a table

JSON

```
  {"data": {
      "id": "100",
      "name": "file name",
      "url": "www.somesite.com/abc/xyz",
       //etc...
   }  }
```

Table

```
ID   | 100
name | file name
url  | www.somesite.com/abc/xyz
```

I'd like to create a dynamic anchor tag with the `url` value as the href - I know this can be done within a callback function once the data is returned, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler (or the simplest) method to accomplish this

Desired table output

```
ID   | 100
name | file name
url  | Click Here! //obviously the link to mysite.com/abc/xyz
```

Comment: Well if you are not reusing the url for anything other than that link you might consider having the whole anchor tag being sent e.g. `"url": "<a href..."`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single AJAX request is asynchronous, so there is no other option but to handle it in a callback (traditional or wrapped in promise).

This is how I would do it:

```
// Get data is some function that makes the request and accepts a callback...
getData(function(data){
    // Build an anchor tag...
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data.url);
    link.innerHTML = 'Click Here!';

    // Add it to the element on the page.
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.appendChild(aTag);
});
```

Make sure you modify the code to add it to the page, it will be different based on your markup.

Inspired By: [How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks bud, I'm generally just trying to leave as little JavaScript element-creation out of my code as possible, but this will work fine

Comment: Can you use other libraries? If so you can limit the amount of code, such as making it a one-liner with jQuery. The only other way that I know how to remove the need to create the elements is by using a templating language. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), [Underscore/Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#template), or even [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)!

Comment: I'm currently using Alloy UI, they might have something in their API but I'm definitely interested in incorporating Angular JS

Comment: I started with Backbone and Handlebars, then switched to Angular. I highly recommend learning Angular! (And Backbone if you have the time, it taught me some great javascript constructs)