# Creat a Dynamic <a href=""> link with JS & JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need some help!

I have HTML code Like this:

```
<div id="Text0">
<a href="x">
<span  class="farbig">Jenkins</span> 
<span  class="farbig1">CMS</span>
</a>
```

And this is my JS Code:

```
var jenkinsinstances={};
jenkinsinstances.cupo={"href":"localhost:2000", "imgsrc":"http://s3.kaercher.../jenkins-cupo.png"};
```

I want to readout the JS code with JQUERY and insert it to all [a href = " "], creating a dynamic link.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what you want??

Comment: `$('a').attr('href', jenkinsinstances.cupo.href)`.... Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "Dynamic link" ? What link do you want in _all_ (?) your `href`? What have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an href on Returned JSON Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019925/creating-an-href-on-returned-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jenkinsinstances = {
  "href": "localhost:2000",
  "imgsrc": "http://s3.kaercher.../jenkins-cupo.png"
};

$("a").each(function(i, v) {

  console.log(jenkinsinstances.href)
  $(this).attr('href', jenkinsinstances.href)
})
$("img").each(function(i, v) {

  $(this).attr('src', jenkinsinstances.imgsrc)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Text0">
  <a href="x">a</a>
  <img src="X" />
  <span class="farbig">Jenkins</span>
  <span class="farbig1">CMS</span>
  </a>
```

Use `.attr()` to set attribute of anchor and img then select it on the object

Answer (score 0):

That would be like this as have only one `anchor` tag.

```
$('#Text0 a').attr('href', jenkinsinstances.cupo.href);
```

```js
var jenkinsinstances = {};
jenkinsinstances.cupo = {
  "href": "localhost:2000",
  "imgsrc": "http://s3.kaercher.../jenkins-cupo.png"
};

console.log($('#Text0 a').attr('href', jenkinsinstances.cupo.href).attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Text0">
  <a href="x">
    <span class="farbig">Jenkins</span>
    <span class="farbig1">CMS</span>
  </a>
</div>
```