# Adding hyperlinks with javascript to html drop down div

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, href, appendchild

I am trying to add more links to this drop down menu, the menu itself works and the links I've provided works as well, the problem is that when I try to add links through a Javascript file using appendChild, nothing seems to be happening. Also the form handling is successful in other codes, the only thing wrong is what is described above.

dropdown.html

```
<body>
<form id="aform">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL">
  <br>
  Bookmark Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="bookmarkname" id="bookmarkname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="formsubmit">
</form> 
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="dropdown">Links</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>
```

dropdown.js

```
function retrieveFormData() {
            var URL = document.getElementById("URL").value;
            var Bookmarkname = document.getElementById("bookmarkname").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
            var aTag = document.createElement('a');
            aTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Bookmarkname))
            aTag.href = URL;
            y.appendChild(aTag);
}
```

So I try to append new  to 'y', but nothing happens in the actual drop down menu, no  is added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

Comment: First two things I would do is check for any javascript errors, then try and alert(y); to make sure you are actually finding it.

Comment: @misaka I am using that information but it does not work for me, exact same code still not appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using a submit button. The submit button tells the browser to send the contents of the form to the server side.

What you want to do is change the submit button to a regular button and add an onclick event.

```
<body>
<form id="aform">
  URL:<br>
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL">
  <br>
  Bookmark Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="bookmarkname" id="bookmarkname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" id="formsubmit" onclick="retrieveFormData();" value="Submit">
</form> 
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="dropdown">Links</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="forminput.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or calling `.preventDefault()` on the event will also work.

Comment: wow haha, yea this was what is happening thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var Bookmarkname = document.getElementById("bookmarkname").value;
```

...will set `Bookmarkname` to the *string* value of `#bookmarkname`. Then you have this line:

```
aTag.appendChild(Bookmarkname);
```

`appendChild` is for appending a child DOM `Node`; it won't work for setting text, so you may be getting a link that has no content. You can, however, do `aTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Bookmarkname))`.

Comment: thanks for your help but this is still not working after I've changed it