# Creating anchor tags dynamically in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, child-nodes

I have a question about anchor tags and javascript.[Converting a URL to an anchor tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myR7q.png)

The text box accepts a url (eg. "www.youtube.com")

I made a Javascript function that adds "http://" to the link.

How do I make it so the convert button adds a link on the webpage that takes you to the website in another tab.

My Javascript code is as follows:

```
var webpage="";
var url="";
var message="";
var x= 0;
var page="";

function convert()
{       
    url=document.getElementById("link").value;
    webpage = "http://" + url;  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could generate the elements and apply the needed attributes to it. Then append the new link to the output paragraph.

```js
function generate() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    
    a.href = 'http://' + document.getElementById('href').value;    
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('href').value));
    document.getElementById('link').appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById('link').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

```html
Link: <input id="href"> <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
<p id="link"></p>
```

Comment: So far this is the only answer to include the ```target``` attribute which addresses the OP's question about opening in another tab, nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this by adding an anchor tag dynamically

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',webpage);
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Please have a look here for more references

[How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addLink()
{       
    var url = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var webpage = "http://" + url;
    
    var a = document.createElement("a");                 // create an anchor element
    a.href = webpage;                                    // set its href
    a.textContent = url;                                 // set its text
    
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(a); // append it to where you want
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<br><br>
<input id="link"/><button onclick='addLink()'>ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to write JavaScript, so I will not go there. The issue is understanding the `target` attribute of an `<a>` tag.

[W3Schools: Target Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_target.asp)