# TypeError: AddEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, treegrid

```
{field: 'actions', title: 'Actions', width: 50, align: 'center',
                                formatter: function (value, row, index) {
                                    if (row.isDirectEntitlements && row.context == "child" && row.isEditing) {
                                        var s = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.save()">Save</a>';
                                        var c = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.cancel()">Cancel</a>';
                                        return s + c;
                                    }
                                    else if (row.isDirectEntitlements) {
                                        var e = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="editBtn" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.edit()" class="btn btn-xs btn-success mar-10 editRow"><i class="material-icons md-18" title=" + localeManager["openiam.ui.common.edit"] + ">mode_edit</i></a>';
                                        e.addEventListener('click',function () {
                                            var s = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.save()">Save</a>';
                                            var c = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.cancel()">Cancel</a>';
                                        },false);
                                        var d = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="deleteBtn" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.deleteRow()" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-new-row doc removeRow"><i class="material-icons md-18" title="Delete">delete</i></a>';
                                        return e + d;
                                    }
                                }
```

I am am trying to add two buttons (save and delete) when I press the edit button but I am stuck on this .addEventListener error. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: The value of `e` is a *string*, not a DOM element reference.

Comment: How would I add an eventListener to a string? Sorry I am new to js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use document.CreateElement function to create html nodes and then on that you can attach event using addEventListener.

This function is available on DOM nodes and not string.

```
var e = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="editBtn" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.edit()" class="btn btn-xs btn-success mar-10 editRow"><i class="material-icons md-18" title=" + localeManager["openiam.ui.common.edit"] + ">mode_edit</i></a>';

//This is just a string and it does not have addEventListener on it
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
//it returns dom node on which you can aad event
anchor.addEventListener('click',function () {
                                            var s = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.save()">Save</a>';
                                           //code
                                        },false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This worked getting around the error, but when I click on edit the the other two buttons dont appear. Do you know why?

Comment: @smarty_pants have you added those buttons to the DOM via appendChild() ?

Comment: Yeah I did something like anchor.appendChild(s) and anchor.appendChild(c)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?
Something like -
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
If so then remember appendChild does not take string , it takes node which is created when you use document.createElement() that means you need to convert s and c in dom nodes.

Comment: I am not, should I be adding buttons a different way?

Comment: How are you creating those buttons, you should create those with document.createElement("a");

Comment: Code: `var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                                        anchor.addEventListener('click',function () {
var s = document.createElement('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.save()">Save</a>');
var c = document.createElement('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.cancel()">Cancel</a>');
                                            anchor.appendChild(s);
                                            anchor.appendChild(c);
                                        },false);`

Comment: you can not give entire tag definition to document.createElement, you need to just give the tag name.in your case var s =  document.createElement('a') and then add further attributes to the s
s.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
for details see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Fix Code: `var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.addEventListener('click',function () {
var s = document.createElement('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.save()">Save</a>');
var c = document.createElement('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cancel()">Cancel</a>');
this.innerHTML=s+c;}, false);
var d = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="deleteBtn" onclick="OPENIAM.UserEntitlement.deleteRow()" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-new-row doc removeRow">< title="Delete">delete</i></a>';return e + d;}}}`